# Add commas to txt file from batch script in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I have this format on a .txt file:

```
"Rosina Merola (rosina_merola@hotmail.com)" <rosina_merola@hotmail.com> 
"Sabina Morales (sabinamorales@gmail.com)" <sabinamorales@gmail.com> 
"Sorella Blanco (zoreblanco@hotmail.com)" <zoreblanco@hotmail.com> 
"Eduardo Schmilinsky Leal" <ejsl41@hotmail.com>
"Elba Rodríguez" <elbameister@gmail.com>
Ernesto Ramirez <ernestoramirezricca@hotmail.com>
```

Some of the names have `""`and a few don't, as you can see in this example.

However, i need to add a comma ',' after each name and before the email line `<>`

I thought that first adding the `""` to every name, it could be easier then to add the commas, i have this code:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (nombresemails.txt) do (
echo "%%a", >> nombresemailscomillas.txt
)
```

It works but it adds the `""` in this format:

```
"Adam Podlinski <apodlinski@cantv.net> ", 
"Adam Podlinski 2 <apodlinski@yahoo.com>", 
""Aldo Gonzalez " <aldodanielg@hotmail.com>", 
""Alejandr Rubin" <rubin4@cantv.net>", 
""Alfredo Huguett " <alfredohuguettc@hotmail.com>", 
""aainiguezf@gmail.com" <aainiguezf@gmail.com>",
```

No matter what are the characters it just adds the `""` even if they already have it, and besides, it adds them to all the line, i just need to add them to every name, leaving the emails inside the `<>` without the `""`.

Anyway, this is just an approach i thought it could work, basically i just need to add a comma after every name and before the emails cointained in `<>`

there is actually some way achieve this on batch code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works here:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (nombresemails.txt) do (
      set "line=%%a"
      set "line=!line: <=,<!"
        >>nombresemailscomillas.txt echo !line!
)
```